# How to specifically shuffle an Array in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var testArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

If I had this array and wanted to shuffle it, I know to use the Fisher-Yates Shuffle, but how would I shuffle it in more of an organized way?

Like, how would I shuffle it but also guarantee that `0` would never appear at the first spot in the array after the shuffle, `1` would never be in the second spot of the array, `2` would never be in the third spot, etc, etc.

Comment: Why not use fisher yates on a slice of the array excluding what you describe? Then rejoin them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using Sattolo's Algorithm, described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Sattolo.27s_algorithm).

It's essentially the same as Fisher-Yates, but with one small change that results in elements of the array not being able to stay in their own positions, which seems to be what you describe.

Answer (score 0):

```
var finalArray = [];

function getUniqueNumber() {
    var uniqueNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 0;
    var doesExist = finalArray.indexOf(uniqueNumber) === -1;

    if (!doesExist) {
        return getUniqueNumber();
    } else {
        return uniqueNumber;
    }
}

function generateTestArray() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        finalArray.push(getUniqueNumber());
    }
    console.log(finalArray);
}
```

This will always generate a test array uniquely jumbling up the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

```
/** fisher yates as seen on wikipedia
 * for i from n−1 downto 1 do
 *   j ← random integer such that 0 ≤ j ≤ i
 *   exchange a[j] and a[i] 
 */

/** modified fisher yates as described
 * for i from n−1 downto 1 do
 *   j ← random integer such that 0 ≤ j ≤ i, j != i, a[j] != i, a[i] != j
 *   exchange a[j] and a[i] (where a[j] != i)
 */

let modifiedFYShuffle = (array) => {
  let swap = (i, j) => {
    let tmp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = tmp;
  }
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    let j = i;
    while (j === i || array[j] === i || array[i] === j) {
      j = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
    }
    swap(i, j)
  }
}

let makeArray = () => {
  let array = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    array[i] = i;
  }
  return array;
}

for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  let array = makeArray();
  modifiedFYShuffle(array);
  console.log(array)
}
```